# Need to convert entire column value in to a mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: vba, excel

Hi my date is in the format yyyymmdd, for eg 20151025 and I need it it mm/dd/yyyy for eg 10/25/2015. I saw many codes but I am confused as it doesn't work when I run or give exactly what I want including one on MSDN. can anyone help?

Comment: What did you try exactly and what were the problems you encountered?

Comment: I tried to do this pDate(i) = Format(pDate(i), "mm / dd/ yyyy ") and get an overflow error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the cells you wish to "fix" and run this short macro:

```
Sub INeedaDate()
   Dim r As Range
   For Each r In Selection
      v = r.Text
      r.Value = DateSerial(Left(v, 4), Mid(v, 5, 2), Right(v, 2))
      r.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
   Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Mid(Str,5,2) & "/" & right(Str,2) & "/" & left(Str,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple one

```
    ActiveSheet.Name = Format$(Date, "MM/DD/YYYY")
```

Answer (score 0):

This formula will make it a date: =DATE(LEFT(A2,4),MID(A2,5,2),RIGHT(A2,2)) and drag down then format the cell into whatever date format you want (MM/DD/YYYY).

You pass a year, month and day into the date formula, we use Left, Mid and Right to chop up the input.

The reason I suggest this is because the date then is an actual date with a number that represents the MS Excel timecode as opposed to text masked as a date, it also removes any issues between different date systems.

Comment: I get an error on the excel sheet as the A2 in my case is not excel sheet but rather it is stored in a variable . So formula doesn't work